# List not Printing in Java JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have  `List<Members> ee = new ArrayList<>();` in Servlet with `Two Members Objects` and then forwarding `ee` as `request.getSession().setAttribute("ee", ee);`, but when I Try to print it in JSP page. nothing displaying.

Here is code that I placed in JSP page.

```
<c:forEach items="${ee}" var="item">
     <c:out value="${item.ID}"/><br />
</c:forEach>
```

Here is Members class code.

```
public class Members {
    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    public void setID(int id){
        this.ID=id;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email=email;
    }
    public int getID(){
        return this.ID;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    } 
}
```

When I view page source of JSP page, I got this source code:

```
<c:forEach items="[Members@4a419a, Members@1b527b6]" var="item">
   <c:out value=""/><br />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing jstl core tags in your page source,it only means that your jsp is not processing your jstl tags as it should.
You need to import jstl tags in your jsp and include the jstl core jar in your classpath of web project

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```